# Load only a few values at a time in a datatable from json file (the first values) for speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I'm loading a datatable using json data saved in an online url. The problem is, when the data gets large (in this case, 10,000+ rows), the datatable takes way too long to load (30+ seconds).

I'm wanting to make it so that it will load only the values needed for the page. At the moment, it's paginated so that about a dozen values show on the page, but I think it's slow because it's loading the entire dataset first.

Is there a way to make it so that only those dozen values load first - rather than wait for the whole thing to load?

It needs to still be responsive to several click/search events, so that when the user searches or clicks several filters, the datatable updates - but I would again prefer that it only shows the first page of results.

**Code**

```js
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/________________.json';
async function populate() {

  const response = await fetch(url);
  const evidenceData = await response.json();
  console.log(evidenceData)

  // Build Table
  function buildTable(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
    table.innerHTML = data.map(function(row) {
      let [country, title, category, date, link, image] = row;

      return `<tr>
                        <td>
                            <br><br>
                            <a href="${link}" target='_blank'>
                            <img class="tableThumbnail" src=${image}><br><br>
                        </td></a>
                        <td>
                            <span class="tableTitle"><br><br><a href="${link}" target='_blank'>${title}</a><br></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>${country}</td>
                        <td>${category}</td>
                        <td>${date}</td>
                    </tr>`;
    }).join('');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('.mydatatable').DataTable({
      "dom": "<<t>ip>",
      "columnDefs": [{
        targets: [2, 3, 4],
        visible: false,
        searchable: true,
      }]
    });
    $('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
      oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
    });
  })

  buildTable(evidenceData)
}

populate();
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Datatables -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="searchInput" class="form-control" placeholder="&#xf002;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="main">
    <table class="table mydatatable" id="mydatatable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> </th>
          <th> </th>
          <th> </th>
          <th> </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="myTable">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've tried a few things here and there with ajax but am not really having much luck in getting it working with this json that is stored on an online url.

Comment: Use DataTables [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). That is why this approach exists - "_There are times when reading data from the DOM is simply too slow or unwieldy, particularly when dealing with many thousands or millions of data rows..._" With this approach, all logic for paging, sorting and filtering is implemented in the server. See also the [examples](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/index.html).

Comment: If your data is provided by a 3rd party which does not, for example, support paging, then you will need to provide your own server in the middle to receive the data and then implement the logic required for server-side processing. Does the API you are hitting not already provide support for paging, etc?

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames! What about using deferRender? I've been trying to make that work but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - **not possible**.

Longer one: a JSON file represents serialized data. Therefore, it *must* get to its end before parsing it. Imagine the following scenario:

```json
{
  "rows": [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 },
    // --> you want it split up until here

    { "id": 5 },
  ]
}
```

Let's say JSON can parse this. What would be the `length` of `rows`? It cannot be 3, because the list was split into chunks and each chunk does not contain equal amount of items. You want to split it until 2, but tomorrow it might be 5. Because it's arbitrary, JSON parser cannot imagine all variations you'd like to have. And keep in mind this is a standard mechanism for data manipulation - what would you do for objects? :)

In your case, there's not much to do since you don't control the JSON file generation. If you want to load something huge, well, you have to wait for it :) You can use some techniques to not block the UI, but that won't save you time.

Comment: Thanks. But what about these kind of solutions?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181508/datatables-how-to-load-only-a-certain-amount-rows-on-page-load

Comment: As the answer suggests, there are two options - either split the response on the server side, querying X items per request, and sending where to start from as a next page (preferred method). Or use a front-end "defer rendering", which means you still get the entire data, but slowly show it on the screen (not to block the UI). Because you don't have control over the backend, you cannot split the request to the big JSON - it will still take time to load. Displaying on the screen is another question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrey Popov. I am trying the deferRender but having no luck - I think I have to go with the client-side option.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74244263/how-do-i-make-deferrender-work-for-datatables-on-a-page-client-side-processing

Comment: That's another story. I wish you luck! For the sake of clean StackOverflow - you can either accept the answer or close your question.