# How do I make DeferRender work for datatables on a page? (Client-Side Processing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, deferred-rendering

I'm trying to use deferRender for my datatables to limit the number of values that first show up. But it does not appear to be making any difference.

The data I am working with has thousands of rows, and I need to use client-side processing (I'm hosting a static page on github pages). The problem I am facing is simply that there are too many values and my page is loading far too slowly.

It needs to still be responsive to several click/search events, so that when the user searches or clicks several filters, the datatable updates - but I would again prefer that it only shows the first page of results.

```js
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/________________.json';
async function populate() {

  const response = await fetch(url);
  const evidenceData = await response.json();
  console.log(evidenceData)

  // Build Table
  function buildTable(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
    table.innerHTML = data.map(function(row) {
      let [country, title, category, date, link, image] = row;

      return `<tr>
                        <td>
                            <br><br>
                            <a href="${link}" target='_blank'>
                            <img class="tableThumbnail" src=${image}><br><br>
                        </td></a>
                        <td>
                            <span class="tableTitle"><br><br><a href="${link}" target='_blank'>${title}</a><br></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>${country}</td>
                        <td>${category}</td>
                        <td>${date}</td>
                    </tr>`;
    }).join('');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('.mydatatable').DataTable({
      "dom": "<<t>ip>",
      "columnDefs": [{
        targets: [2, 3, 4],
        visible: false,
        searchable: true,
      }]
    });
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Datatables -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="searchInput" class="form-control" placeholder="&#xf002;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="main">
    <table class="table mydatatable" id="mydatatable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> </th>
          <th> </th>
          <th> </th>
          <th> </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="myTable">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "_How do I make deferRender work?_" - Just add `"deferRender": true` - as shown in the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender).

Comment: However, there is no guarantee that it will help you, in this specific case. You are already building all the HTML using the non-DataTables `fetch(url)` function. And even if you were using DataTables Ajax instead of `fetch`, then how long does it take to fetch all the data across the network, compared to what you would save by using `deferRender`? You can maybe get an improvement by using `deferRender` with DataTables built-in support for Ajax. You will no longer need any of that "build the HTML manually using strings" logic.

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames, but for whatever reason it doesn't appear to be working. Even when I add ajax. Check out this additional detail/sample here where I'm also trying to solve the ajax issue... https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/213936#Comment_213936

Comment: I am not surprised. That's why I said "_you can **maybe** get an improvement_". There are probably multiple factors here - and `deferRender` may improve performance - but not enough for you to notice, given other performance bottlenecks. The team at the DataTables forum will have more insight that I do, for sure. This does not mean `deferRender` is not working. It may well be working just fine.

Comment: I've created a new post with that more specific question. The problem here is that once I include the ajax line, it doesn't even load any data. @andrewJames
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255064/how-to-load-json-into-datatables-using-ajax-for-client-side-processing