# How to load JSON into DataTables using ajax for client-side processing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to make ajax and deferRender work but am not having any luck. I've followed the documentation on their page but can't seem to get it read into the dataset.

Notes:

- I'm using client-side processing.
- Imagine the data.json is just in the root folder, literally right next to the index.html file.

Basically what happens when I try this is it just doesn't even load the data.

**JSON**

```
 {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Bangladesh"
            },
            {
                "name": "Bhutan"
            },
            {
                "name": "Cambodia"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**JS**

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#example").DataTable({
                ajax: "data.json",
                columns: [{ data: "name" }],
                serverSide: false,
                deferRender: true,
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
</body>
```

Comment: What error do you get? Look in the browser's console (F12 to open). I expect you will see an error something like this: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource...`.  Modern browsers will prevent you from opening files from the filesystem via Ajax, for security reasons (like the [DataTables team](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/213973/#Comment_213973) said).

Comment: Why aren't you using a URL to retrieve your data like you did in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74244263/how-do-i-make-deferrender-work-for-datatables-on-a-page-client-side-processing)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below method.

HTML code => add a tbody tag and assign an id

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="example_tbody">
            
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
</body>
```

In JS add the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get({
        url: 'data.json',
        success: function(res){
            var list = ''; //declare an empty variable here
            $.each(res.data, function(i){ //foreach loop for loop through data.json file
               list += '<tr>'; //don't forget (+=) signs here otherwise only the last data in data.json will be shown in your table
               list += '<td>'+res.data[i].name+'</td>';
               list += '</tr>';
            })

            $("#example_tbody").html(list); //table body id here //to print data in table
            $("#example").DataTable(); //table id here
        }
    })
});
```

this will throw an error if you are working on local files. You have to host your website or use localhost to correct that error.

Comment: This throws an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`. Also, even if you fix that, how can your code automatically access the `data.json` file (which is on the local filesystem) from the browser?

Comment: check edited code above.

Comment: @DeshanDissanayake this doesn't work. My question is in the case of when the data.json is not on a server but as part of the root folder